# Converting TArray<string> to string (Delphi 10.2 Tokyo)

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, directory

I want to convert a `TArray<string>` which is second parameter of third SelectDirectory (`out Directories` parameter) function to string to write selected path to edit box.

But I don't allow the user for multiple selection. So, only one directory can be selected.

What should I do?

Comment: Check the count (which should be zero or 1) and if it is 1, select the zeroth element.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here.  Are you asking how to index an array?

Comment: What do you want to appear in the string when the array has multiple elements.

Answer (score 13):

Although you mention only the special case with a one-element-array, a general approach to convert a `TArray<string>` into a single string with all the array elements separated by a given string is using `string.Join`:

```
const
  sep = ',';
var
  arr: TArray<string>;
  S: string;
begin
  S := string.Join(sep, arr);
end;
```

Comment: Didn't knew until now about join function. Cool

Answer (score 2):

If `SelectDirectory()` returns True, the output array is guaranteed to have *at least* 1 element in it.  Since you don't enable multiple selection, the array is guaranteed to have *only* 1 element in it.  So just access that element by index:

```
var
  dirs: TArray<string>;

if SelectDirectory('', dirs) then
  Edit1.Text := dirs[0]; // <--
```